# What is the method for generating urls using RouteLink when a route name is not supplied?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Using `@Html.RouteLink` with a route name simply directs the routing engine to use the route of that name. This is easy to understand and also apparently the only way anyone who writes a blog entry or the documentation attempts to explain RouteLink.

I appreciate that this is the preferred method and I too have always used a route name with RouteLink but I want to know how it works when we don't and I cant find any really good info on it. So the method is question is:

```
public static MvcHtmlString RouteLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    RouteValueDictionary routeValues
)
```

and in keeping with all the interesting stuff on MSDN, [it's not explained at all](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460117(v=vs.118).aspx).

Haacked.com [has examples of using RouteLink](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/11/21/named-routes-to-the-rescue.aspx/) in this manner:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Test",
    url: "code/p/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Section", action = "Index", id = "" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);

@Html.RouteLink("Test", new {controller="section", action="Index", id=123})

@Html.RouteLink("Default", new {controller="Home", action="Index", id=123})
```

When I read that I thought it was a typo that both would actually bind to "Default" but no it actually works. The link with the text "Test" generates as `https://localhost:44301/code/p/Index/123`.

It seemed "wrong" because to me the default values are normally used when none are supplied but here they are being use as lookup values during generation. It's weird and loose and I can't remember ever having done it this way nor can I think of a reason why I would ever do it this way.

If I do this :

```
 @Html.RouteLink("Test", new {controller="sectionA", action="Index", id=123})
```

it doesn't work but if I do this :

```
 @Html.RouteLink("Test", new {controller="section", action="IndexA", id=123})
```

it still does so it seems only the controller value is significant and yet it's completely unused as far as the generated url goes.

`https://localhost:44301/code/p/Index/123`

At Haacked.com, Phil says:

> There’s even more details I’ve glossed over having to do with how a
>   route’s default values figure into URL generation. That’s a topic for
>   another time, but it explains why you don’t run into this problem with
>   routes to controller actions which have an URL without parameters.

But it doesn't seem he ever got back to that topic. I've looked at the source but  I'm 30 calls deep and wandering into abstract classes that lead nowhere and I'm not in a position to step through it off a symbol server right now.

So is it as simple as "controller names become route names, in the absence of actual route names during url generation"? And if so why did they do/ allow this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've a hunt around and to paraphrase [Professional ASP.NET MVC 4
 By Jon Galloway, Phil Haack, Brad Wilson, K. Scott Allen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/111834846X) in the scenario outlined in my question, default values not present in the url become a keyed switch of sorts that must be supplied with values that match the defaults in the RouteLink in order for that link to be considered a match for url generation.

So if you have a route like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Test",
    url: "code/p/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Section", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

Then in order for it to be considered you must supply a controller="section" value in the routelink. `{action}` doesn't matter as it's part of the url and `{controller}` itself is not significant. It's any `{parameter}` with a default value not in the url.

So given

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Test",
    url: "code/p/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { fruit = "bananas", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

We'd need to supply a fruit="bananas" in my RouteLink

```
@Html.RouteLink("Test", new {fruit="bananas", action="IndexA", id=123})
```

Also note that it's *not* based on order. So it's not that the first `{parameter}` not present in the url becomes the key, it's all `{parameter}` not present in the url become the key so in effect you could have a composite key as per:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Test",
    url: "code/p/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { fruit = "bananas", insect="honeybee", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

You'd need a `RouteLink` defined as below for a match:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Test", new {fruit="bananas", insect="honeybee", action="IndexA", id=123})
```

If you Google

> a detailed look at url generation

You'll get the Google books link for the pages that explain this. I refer to this as a "keyed switch" because as per the flow chart a matching key turns route consideration on and off for a given route.

I still can't think of a good reason as to why I'd ever do this over a named route and thus why it's specifically supported.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that `@Html.ActionLink()` and `@Html.RouteLink` do the same thing if the route name is not passed.

Take a look at the following method (found in `RouteCollectionExtensions.cs`). `name` parameter is the route name here.

```
internal static VirtualPathData GetVirtualPathForArea(this RouteCollection routes, RequestContext requestContext, string name, RouteValueDictionary values, out bool usingAreas)
{
  if (routes == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("routes");
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
  {
    usingAreas = false;
    return routes.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, name, values);
  }
  string areaName = (string) null;
  if (values != null)
  {
    object obj;
    if (values.TryGetValue("area", out obj))
      areaName = obj as string;
    else if (requestContext != null)
      areaName = AreaHelpers.GetAreaName(requestContext.RouteData);
  }
  RouteValueDictionary values1 = values;
  RouteCollection routeCollection = RouteCollectionExtensions.FilterRouteCollectionByArea(routes, areaName, out usingAreas);
  if (usingAreas)
  {
    values1 = new RouteValueDictionary((IDictionary<string, object>) values);
    values1.Remove("area");
  }
  return routeCollection.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, values1);
}
```

You can see that it takes different actions based upon if the route name is null or not.

To answer your question, behavior for both the `@Html.ActionLink()` and `@Html.RouteLink()` will be the same (they will select the same route based upon configuration) if the route name is not passed.

**Update**

I am not sure how the controller name can become the route name because in the following method call you can see the nulls are being passed along for both the action name and controller name :

```
public static string GenerateRouteLink(RequestContext requestContext, RouteCollection routeCollection, string linkText, string routeName, string protocol, string hostName, string fragment, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
  return HtmlHelper.GenerateLinkInternal(requestContext, routeCollection, linkText, routeName, (string) null, (string) null, protocol, hostName, fragment, routeValues, htmlAttributes, false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had already dug this deep and a bit further. I probably should have used the word "rule" as opposed to "method" in the title of my post. I think the actual method where all this plays out is System.Web.Routing.Route.Match.